# How to use runBlocking with an Apollo client?

Tags: kotlin, graphql, apollo, kotlin-coroutines

I am using the Apollo client in a Kotlin app (JVM command line app, not Android) to fetch paginated data, with each "page" being added to a single list. In theory, using runBlocking should allow the calling function to get the data fetched by the Apollo client, but it doesn't seem to work in practice - see example code below. What is the correct (or at least, better) way to accomplish this?

```
// Simple pagination using Apollo client
class FooSource(private val query: String, private val apolloClient: ApolloClient) {

    override suspend fun load(params: PageParams): LoadResult<Foo> {
        val response = try {
            apolloClient.query(
                FooQuery(
                    queryString = query,
                    pageSize = params.pageSize,
                    cursor = params.cursorNext
                )
            ).execute()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return LoadResult(e)
        }

        // Successfully prints a non-zero list size
        println("Source data: ${response.data.size}")
        return LoadResult(result.data, result.endCursor)
    }
}

// Fetch the data 
fun getData(query: String, apolloClient: ApolloClient) {
    var source = FoodSource(query, apolloClient)
    val data = mutableListOf<T>()
    var hasNext = false

    do {
        val result  = runBlocking {
            source.load(params)
        }
        // Shows as zero, since we always recieve an empty list
        println("Recieved data: ${response.data.size}")
        data.addAll(result.data)
        params.cursorNext = result.cursorNext
        hasNext = result.hasNext()

    } while (hasNext)
}
```